# Display and Parse XML Form Results on New Page

Tags: php, xml, get

I have a form that right now diverts to a different URL and gives back the results in XML format. Instead of going to the URL (http://99.999.999.999:81/fmi...) I want it to just display the data on my site (can be a new page). So that it's still hosted on my site.

This is my current form code:

```
<script>
function process()
{
var url="http://99.999.999.999:81/fmi/xml/fmresultset.xml?-db=Front_Desk&-lay=WebRoomQuery&-findany&-script=WebQueryPSOS&-script.param=snug," + document.getElementById("start").value + "," + document.getElementById("end").value;
location.href=url;
return false;
}
</script>
<form onSubmit="return process();">
Start Date: <input type="text" id="start" name="start">
End Date: <input type="text" id="end" name="end"> 
<input type="submit" value="go">

</form>
```

And this is what I tried:

```
<script>
function process()
{
var url="http://99.999.999.999:81/fmi/xml/fmresultset.xml?-db=Front_Desk&-lay=WebRoomQuery&-findany&-script=WebQueryPSOS&-script.param=snug," + document.getElementById("start").value + "," + document.getElementById("end").value;
location.href=url;
return false;
}
</script>
<form action="results.php" method="get">
Start Date: <input type="text" id="start" name="start">
End Date: <input type="text" id="end" name="end"> 
<input type="submit" value="go">

</form>
```

But it doesn't work (I didn't think it would). I'm just not sure how to get it to work. I know I need to use the $_GET method, but am not sure how to work it with the above. My website is Wordpress; not sure if that makes any difference to anything.

Comment: You would need to learn and/or use AJAX to do this. Here is a [quick example](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_xmlfile.asp).

Comment: @Mikey thanks. What if I didn't do it on the same page and it went to a different page; then I think I can do PHP?